# Please help me out with this Azure function trigger code in C#

Tags: c#, azure

**PS C:\Users\Wavy\Downloads\blogresume-master\backend\api> func host start
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.
C:\Users\Wavy\Downloads\blogresume-master\backend\api\Counter.cs(1,22): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected [C:\Users\Wavy\Downloads\blogresume-master\backend\api\api.csproj]
C:\Users\Wavy\Downloads\blogresume-master\backend\api\Counter.cs(1,22): error CS1026: )
expected [C:\Users\Wavy\Downloads\blogresume-master\backend\api\api.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Users\Wavy\Downloads\blogresume-master\backend\api\Counter.cs(1,22): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected [C:\Users\Wavy\Downloads\blogresume-master\backend\api\api.csproj]
C:\Users\Wavy\Downloads\blogresume-master\backend\api\Counter.cs(1,22): error CS1026: )
expected [C:\Users\Wavy\Downloads\blogresume-master\backend\api\api.csproj]
0 Warning(s)
2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.62**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class GetResume
    {
        [FunctionName("GetResume")]
        public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [CosmosDB(databaseName:"Azureresume", collectionName: "Counter", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureResumeConnectionString" , Id = "1", PartitionKey = "1" )] Counter counter,
            [CosmosDB(databaseName:"Azureresume", collectionName: "Counter", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureResumeConnectionString" , Id = "1", PartitionKey = "1" )] out Counter updatedCounter,
            ILogger log)
       {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            updatedCounter = counter;
            updatedCounter.Count += 1;

            var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(counter);

            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You need to read and understand errors from the compiler:

C:\Users\Wavy\Downloads\blogresume-master\backend\api\Counter.cs(1,22) error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected

Counter.cs has a compilation error on line 1 column 22.  An open bracket is expected.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am ew to c#, below is my Counter.cs                               
 Using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Company.function

{
    public class Counter
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="count")]
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Can you include it in the question?